# In a topological product, does an open set equal the union of inverse projection of projection of the set?

Tags: general-topology

Namely, in $\prod_{\alpha\in I} X_\alpha$, does an open set $O = \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}p_{\alpha}^{-1}(p_{\alpha}(O))$?

And I really cannot grasp the idea of $p_{\alpha}(O)$, since $O$ is a union of a finite number of $p_{\alpha}^{-1}(O_{\alpha})$, when I form the $\alpha$th projection I can't simply take the union of every open sets that are taken in $X_{\alpha}$.

---

I think I'm confused by a single fact. In $\Bbb R^2$, is the projection of $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \lt 1\}$ on $x$-axis $(-1,1)$? In that case, the unit circle is neither a union nor an intersection of the inverse projection of its projections.

Comment: My second question is basically: what does $p_{\alpha}(O)$ look like

Comment: $O$ is a union of finite intersections of sets of the form $p^{-1}_{\alpha }(U_{\alpha })$ where $U_{\alpha }\in \mathcal T(X_{\alpha })$

Comment: But can $p_{\alpha}(O)$ be expressed explicitly?

Comment: Your understanding of the second part is correct. The open unit disk or radius $1$ centred at the origin projects to $(-1,1)$ on both axes. The intersection of the inverse projections is the open square $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$, and the union of the inverse projections is an unbounded $+$ sign, a fattening up of the coordinate axes whose arms have width $2$.

Comment: What do you mean can $p_{\alpha}(O)$ be expressed explicitly? The most that can be said is that if $O$ is open in the product topology, then $p_{\alpha}(O)$ is open in $X_{\alpha}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally not so. In $R^2$ let $O=\{(x,y) :  -1<x+y<1\}.$ For the projections $p_1$ and $p_2$ onto the co-ordinate axes we have $ p_1(O)=p_2(O)=R$ so for $j \in \{1,2\}$ we have $ p_j^{-1}(p_j(O))=R^2$. Observe that $O= \cup \{ (x,x+1)\times (-x-1, -x) : x \in R\}$ is open........Regarding the second Q, the projection of $O=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ onto the $x$-axis is $p_x(O)=\{x : \exists y ((x,y)\in O\}$ which of course is $(-1,1).$ Note that if $S \subset R$ then $p_x(S)=S\times R$.....The open disc is a union of finite intersections of inverse projections of open sets: For each point $p=(x,y) \in O$ take $d_p>0$ such that $ W(p)=(x-d_p,x+d_p)\times (y-d_p, y+d_p) \subset O . $ For brevity let $U_p=(x-d_p,x+d_p)$  and $V_p=(y-d_p,y+d_p).$  We have $p \in (p_x^{-1} U_p)\cap  (p_y^{-1}V_p)=W_p\subset O$ so $O=\cup _{p \in O}[(p_x^{-1}U_p)\cap ( p_y^{-1}V_p)]. $

Comment: Oh I see. And could you have a look at the second half of my question?

Comment: i added something about the second half to my answer